# Python BeautifulSoup not finding all href tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the weeks link schedule listed on this page
[Schedule](https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2022/seasontype/1)

This links are in the html format listed here.

```
<div class="custom--week"><a href="/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2022/seasontype/1" tabindex="0"><span class="week week-range">HOF</span><span class="week">Aug 1 - 9</span></a></div>
```

My issuse is my code only gets week 1 link instead of all the week links on the page.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2022/seasontype/1'
dflnk = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description','link']) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('link')

for link in links:
  dlink = link['href']
 
  if link['href'] != None:
    
    if '/nfl/schedule/' in link['href']: #link.get('href'):
       print('nfl')
       print(link['href'])
    else:
      hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link['href'] #Convert relative URL to absolute URL
      
      if 'week' in link['href']:
         columns = list(dflnk)
         values = [dlink,hlink]
         zipped = zip(columns, values)
         a_dictionary = dict(zipped)
         dflnk = dflnk.append(a_dictionary, ignore_index = True)
          
  print('------------End----------------') # Just a line break
```

Code does not fail but only returns links for week 1. Based on this logic shouldn't it return all weeks on page up to week 3? That's what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: `soup.find_all('link')` gets all `<link>` tags, **not** all `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is loaded by JavaScript and bs4 can't render JS. So you can apply an automation tool something like selenium. Here I use `selenium with bs4` to grab the desired data.

***Example:***

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2022/seasontype/1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
data =[]
for e in soup.select('.custom--week'):
    description = e.get_text(strip=True)
    link = 'https://www.espn.com' + e.a.get('href')
    #print(link)
    data.append({
        'Description':description,
        'Link':link
    })


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Description                                   Link
0             HOFAug 1 - 9  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/yea...
1      Pre wk 1Aug 10 - 16  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/2/yea...
2      Pre wk 2Aug 17 - 23  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/3/yea...
3   Pre wk 3Aug 24 - Sep 7  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/4/yea...
4         Week 1Sep 8 - 13  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/yea...
5        Week 2Sep 14 - 20  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/2/yea...
6        Week 3Sep 21 - 27  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/3/yea...
7     Week 4Sep 28 - Oct 4  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/4/yea...
8         Week 5Oct 5 - 11  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/5/yea...
9        Week 6Oct 12 - 18  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/6/yea...
10       Week 7Oct 19 - 25  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/7/yea...
11    Week 8Oct 26 - Nov 1  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/8/yea...
12         Week 9Nov 2 - 8  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/9/yea...
13       Week 10Nov 9 - 15  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/10/ye...
14      Week 11Nov 16 - 22  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/11/ye...
15      Week 12Nov 23 - 29  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/12/ye...
16   Week 13Nov 30 - Dec 6  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/13/ye...
17       Week 14Dec 7 - 13  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/14/ye...
18      Week 15Dec 14 - 20  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/15/ye...
19      Week 16Dec 21 - 27  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/16/ye...
20   Week 17Dec 28 - Jan 3  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/17/ye...
21   Week 17Dec 28 - Jan 3  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/17/ye...
22       Week 18Jan 4 - 11  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/18/ye...
23    Wild CardJan 12 - 17  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/yea...
24       Div RdJan 18 - 24  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/2/yea...
25   Conf ChampJan 25 - 31  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/3/yea...
26       Pro BowlFeb 1 - 7  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/4/yea...
27    Super BowlFeb 8 - 14  https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/5/yea...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go through the espn api to avoid selenium. Not sure it's all that quicker in this case.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

season = 2022
url = f'https://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/football/leagues/nfl/seasons/{season}/types'

jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
seasonTypeLinks = [x['$ref'] for x in jsonData['items']]

df_list = []
for url in seasonTypeLinks:
    print(url)
    #url = seasonTypeLinks[1]
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    weeksLink = jsonData['weeks']['$ref']
    
    jsonData = requests.get(weeksLink).json()
    weekItems = [jsonData['items']][0]
    for week in weekItems:
        weekUrl = week['$ref']
        jsonData = requests.get(weekUrl).json()
        
        temp_df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData)
        temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns = {x:x.replace('$ref', 'url') for x in temp_df.columns})
        
        df_list.append(temp_df)
        
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score -2):

The main reason is because you just scraping from only 1 page when 3 weeks presents for 3 seperately pages so try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for number in range(3):
  URL = f'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/{number}/year/2022/seasontype/{number}'
  dflnk = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Description','link']) 

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  links = soup.find_all('link')

  for link in links:
    dlink = link['href']
 
    if link['href'] != None:
    
      if '/nfl/schedule/' in link['href']: #link.get('href'):
        print('nfl')
        print(link['href'])
      else:
        hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link['href'] #Convert relative URL to absolute URL
      
        if 'week' in link['href']:
          columns = list(dflnk)
          values = [dlink,hlink]
          zipped = zip(columns, values)
          a_dictionary = dict(zipped)
          dflnk = dflnk.append(a_dictionary, ignore_index = True)
          
  print('------------End----------------') # Just a line break
```